# Cocoapod system setup issue - Error on 'pod install'

Tags: ios, ruby, terminal, cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods 1.9.0. I am having an issue with a bunch of ruby errors being thrown when I run 'pod install' or 'pod update'. I have tried reinstalling several different versions of ruby to fix the issue with no success.

Look like it could be a system setup issue. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

````
Process memory map:
10e101000-10e102000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
10e102000-10e103000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
10e103000-10e104000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
10e104000-10e106000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e106000-10e107000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e107000-10e108000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e108000-10e426000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e426000-10e42c000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e42c000-10e43d000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e43d000-10e514000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
10e514000-10e570000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
10e570000-10e571000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
10e571000-10e57b000 r-- /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.1.2_2/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
10e57b000-10e57c000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e57c000-10e582000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e582000-10e583000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e583000-10e584000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e584000-10e58a000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e58a000-10e58b000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e58b000-10e58c000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e58c000-10e58d000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e58d000-10e5cd000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e5cd000-10e5e8000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e5e8000-10e6e8000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
10e6e8000-1106e8000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1106e8000-1106fc000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1106fc000-110714000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110714000-110715000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110715000-1107b6000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1107b6000-1107b7000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1107b7000-110858000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110858000-110859000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110859000-1108fa000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1108fa000-1108fb000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1108fb000-11099c000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11099c000-11099d000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11099d000-110a3e000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110a3e000-110a3f000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110a3f000-110ae0000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110ae0000-110ae1000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110ae1000-110b82000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110b82000-110b83000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110b83000-110c24000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110c24000-110c25000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110c25000-110cc6000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110cc6000-110cc7000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110cc7000-110d68000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110d68000-110d69000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110d69000-110e0a000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110e0a000-110e0b000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110e0b000-110eac000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110eac000-110ead000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110ead000-110f4e000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110f4e000-110f4f000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110f4f000-110ff0000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110ff0000-110ff1000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
110ff1000-111092000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111092000-111093000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111093000-111134000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111134000-111135000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111135000-1111d6000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1111d6000-1111d7000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1111d7000-111278000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111278000-111279000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111279000-11131a000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11131a000-11131b000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11131b000-1113bc000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1113bc000-1113bd000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1113bd000-11145e000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11145e000-11145f000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11145f000-111500000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111500000-111501000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111501000-1115a2000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1115a2000-1115a3000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1115a3000-111644000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111644000-111645000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111645000-1116e6000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1116e6000-1116e7000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1116e7000-111788000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111788000-111789000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111789000-11182a000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11182a000-11182b000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11182b000-1118cc000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1118cc000-1118cd000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
1118cd000-11196e000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11196e000-11196f000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
11196f000-111a10000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111a10000-111a11000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111a11000-111ab2000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111ab2000-111ab3000 --- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111ab3000-111b54000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111b54000-111b56000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111b56000-111b57000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111b57000-111b58000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/encdb.bundle
111b58000-111b70000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
111b70000-111b72000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
111b72000-111b73000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
111b73000-111b74000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
111b74000-111b83000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/monitor.bundle
111b83000-111b9b000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/monitor.bundle
111b9b000-111bb8000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/monitor.bundle
111bb8000-111bf1000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/monitor.bundle
111bf1000-111bf2000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/monitor.bundle
111bf2000-111bf3000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/monitor.bundle
111bf3000-111bf4000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/monitor.bundle
111bf4000-111c54000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/pathname.bundle
111c54000-111c5a000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/pathname.bundle
111c5a000-111c5b000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/pathname.bundle
111c5b000-111c60000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/pathname.bundle
111c60000-111c62000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/cgi/escape.bundle
111c62000-111c63000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/cgi/escape.bundle
111c63000-111c64000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/cgi/escape.bundle
111c64000-111c94000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/date_core.bundle
111c94000-111cda000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/date_core.bundle
111cda000-111cdb000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/date_core.bundle
111cdb000-111cdc000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/date_core.bundle
111cdc000-111cf9000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/date_core.bundle
111cf9000-111d0e000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/bigdecimal.bundle
111d0e000-111d0f000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/bigdecimal.bundle
111d0f000-111d15000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/bigdecimal.bundle
111d15000-111d32000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/etc.bundle
111d32000-111d6b000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/etc.bundle
111d6b000-111d6f000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/etc.bundle
111d6f000-111d70000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/etc.bundle
111d70000-111d73000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/etc.bundle
111d73000-111d7a000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/stringio.bundle
111d7a000-111d7b000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/stringio.bundle
111d7b000-111d7f000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/stringio.bundle
111d7f000-111d81000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest.bundle
111d81000-111d82000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest.bundle
111d82000-111d84000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest.bundle
111d84000-111d88000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/strscan.bundle
111d88000-111d89000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/strscan.bundle
111d89000-111d8c000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/strscan.bundle
111d8c000-111dad000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/socket.bundle
111dad000-111dae000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/socket.bundle
111dae000-111dbd000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/socket.bundle
111dbd000-111dbe000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/io/wait.bundle
111dbe000-111dbf000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/io/wait.bundle
111dbf000-111dc0000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/io/wait.bundle
111dc0000-111dcc000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/zlib.bundle
111dcc000-111dcd000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/zlib.bundle
111dcd000-111dd5000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/zlib.bundle
111dd5000-111de6000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib/libz.1.2.11.dylib
111de6000-111de7000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib/libz.1.2.11.dylib
111de7000-111de9000 r-- /usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11/lib/libz.1.2.11.dylib
111de9000-111deb000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/windows_31j.bundle
111deb000-111dec000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/windows_31j.bundle
111dec000-111ded000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/windows_31j.bundle
111ded000-111df2000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/json/ext/parser.bundle
111df2000-111df3000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/json/ext/parser.bundle
111df3000-111df5000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/json/ext/parser.bundle
111df5000-111dfc000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/json/ext/generator.bundle
111dfc000-111dfd000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/json/ext/generator.bundle
111dfd000-111e01000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/json/ext/generator.bundle
111e01000-111ec1000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
111ec1000-111efa000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
111efa000-111efd000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
111efd000-111efe000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
111efe000-111f2d000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle
111f2d000-111f7c000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
111f7c000-111f89000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
111f89000-111fa4000 r-- /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
111fa4000-112140000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
112140000-11216b000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
11216b000-11216e000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
11216e000-1121d1000 r-- /usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib
1121d1000-1121d2000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/io/nonblock.bundle
1121d2000-1121d3000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/io/nonblock.bundle
1121d3000-1121d4000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/io/nonblock.bundle
1121d4000-112234000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha2.bundle
112234000-112235000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha2.bundle
112235000-112236000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha2.bundle
112236000-112237000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha2.bundle
112237000-112252000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
112252000-112253000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
112253000-112254000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
112254000-112268000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/gems/ruby-head/gems/ffi-1.12.2/lib/ffi_c.bundle
112268000-112269000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha1.bundle
112269000-11226a000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha1.bundle
11226a000-11226b000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha1.bundle
11226b000-11226c000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/sha1.bundle
11226c000-112270000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/psych.bundle
112270000-112271000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/psych.bundle
112271000-112275000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/psych.bundle
112275000-11228d000 r-x /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.2/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib
11228d000-11228e000 rw- /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.2/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib
11228e000-112290000 r-- /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.2.2/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib
112290000-112350000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112350000-112445000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112445000-112505000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112505000-112511000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112511000-112541000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112541000-112601000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112601000-112681000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112681000-112801000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112801000-112802000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112802000-112803000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112803000-112804000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16le.bundle
112804000-112805000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16be.bundle
112805000-112806000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16be.bundle
112806000-112807000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/enc/utf_16be.bundle
112807000-112808000 r-x /Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.cHOav9Nk
112808000-112809000 r-x /Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.cHOav9Nk
112809000-112810000 r-- /Library/Preferences/Logging/.plist-cache.cHOav9Nk
112810000-112828000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/md5.bundle
112828000-112829000 r-x /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/md5.bundle
112829000-11282a000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/md5.bundle
11282a000-11282b000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-darwin18/digest/md5.bundle
11282b000-112858000 rw- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
112858000-11285b000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/bin/ruby
11285b000-112c56000 r-- /Users/davidbalcher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/libruby.2.7.dylib
112c56000-112c7d000 r-- /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
11b164000-11b1f5000 r-x /usr/lib/dyld
11b1f5000-11b1fa000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
11b1fa000-11b1fb000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
11b1fb000-11b230000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
11b230000-11b268000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
700005ba8000-700005ba9000 --- /usr/lib/dyld
700005ba9000-700005c2b000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
700005c2b000-700005c2c000 --- /usr/lib/dyld
700005c2c000-700005e2e000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
700005e2e000-700005e2f000 --- /usr/lib/dyld
700005e2f000-700006031000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
700006031000-700006032000 --- /usr/lib/dyld
700006032000-700006234000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
700006234000-700006235000 --- /usr/lib/dyld
700006235000-700006437000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb36400000-7fdb36500000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb36500000-7fdb36600000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb36600000-7fdb36700000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb36700000-7fdb36800000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb36800000-7fdb37000000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb37000000-7fdb37800000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb37800000-7fdb38000000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38000000-7fdb38800000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38800000-7fdb38900000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38900000-7fdb38a00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38a00000-7fdb38b00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38b00000-7fdb38c00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38c00000-7fdb38d00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38d00000-7fdb38e00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38e00000-7fdb38f00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb38f00000-7fdb39000000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb39000000-7fdb39800000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb39800000-7fdb3a000000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a000000-7fdb3a100000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a100000-7fdb3a200000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a200000-7fdb3a300000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a300000-7fdb3a400000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a400000-7fdb3a500000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a500000-7fdb3a600000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a600000-7fdb3a700000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a700000-7fdb3a800000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3a800000-7fdb3b000000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3b000000-7fdb3b100000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3b100000-7fdb3b200000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3b200000-7fdb3b300000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3b300000-7fdb3b400000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3b400000-7fdb3b500000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3b500000-7fdb3b600000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3b800000-7fdb3c000000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fdb3c000000-7fdb3c800000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7ffeddaff000-7ffee12ff000 --- /usr/lib/dyld
7ffee12ff000-7ffee1aff000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff00000000-7fff80000000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff80000000-7fff8ac00000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8ac00000-7fff8ae00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8ae00000-7fff8b600000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8b600000-7fff8b800000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8b800000-7fff8ba00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8ba00000-7fff8bc00000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8bc00000-7fff8be00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8be00000-7fff8d200000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8d200000-7fff8d400000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff8d400000-7fff90a00000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff90a00000-7fff90c00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff90c00000-7fff93800000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff93800000-7fff93a00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff93a00000-7fff93c00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff93c00000-7fff93e00000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff93e00000-7fff94000000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff94000000-7fff94400000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff94400000-7fff94600000 rw- /usr/lib/dyld
7fff94600000-7fffc0000000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fffc0000000-7fffffe00000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fffffe00000-7fffffe01000 r-- /usr/lib/dyld
7fffffe2c000-7fffffe2d000 r-x /usr/lib/dyld```
````

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- downgrade to Ruby 2.6.5
  https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.15-catalina

`export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" eval "$(rbenv init -)"
rbenv global 2.6.5`

`ruby -v`

`gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.0`

`gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2`

`gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.4.0`